# footer with position:fixed not respnding to margin-right

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that I have a footer with a `position:fixed` and I have a div encapsulating everything called frontier. Through frontier, I set the margin-right and left to `200px` which works expect for the footer on the right side.

Css for frontier and footer styles:

```
#frontier
{
 margin-right:200px;
 margin-left:200px;
}


.footer
{
background-color: #000000;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:100px;   /* Height of the footer */
opacity: 0.7;
text-align: center;

-webkit-box-shadow: -6px -8px 6px -6px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: -6px -8px 6px -6px #999;
box-shadow: -6px -8px 6px -6px #999;
}
```

I've tried a few things suggested but i still can't get the footer to respond. And i feel like this is going to be an issue for anything that I add with a fixed position. any solutions? thankyou

HTML

```
<nav class='footer' onload='startTime()'>
   <h1 id='hours'></h>
   <h1> :</h1>
   <h1 id='minutes'></h1>
   <h1> :</h1>
   <h1 id='seconds'></h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the html? Can create the snippet? And yes. margin will not effect to fixed div which you give parent div.

Comment: Fixed positioning attach the element to the document, not the parent element. So your fixed div will be positioned relative to `<body>` tag, not to your `#frontier` div. However, you need to share the HTML to see exactly your problem.

Comment: I have added the HTML I made it as using nav, does that matter?

Comment: You need to share all your html since #frontier div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have understood "position: fixed" entirely. Position fixed is always relative to the viewport. Therefore 100% will always be 100% of the viewport and not of the encapsulating element.

The previous answer recommends adding the margins to the fixed element which is not going to work either. What you need to do is add a div inside your fixed element, and on that element you can apply margins.

For example:

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="content">
       footer
   </div>
</div>

.footer
{
    background-color: #000000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.content
{
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

However I suppose what you actually want to do is add a padding to your footer (leaving 200px on both the left and right side) and then you can apply it directly to your fixed element. Please note that for a padding to work well with 100% width you need box-sizing: border-box;

```
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>

.footer
{
    background-color: #000000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    padding:0 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Edit, attached a fiddle to show what I think you are trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/mtjkp2fv/1/

Comment: @user3676224 what do you mean it's not working? It's working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0c8otw8q/

Comment: I need it to be both indented from the left and right, currently its just doing the right.

Comment: http://torontoview.net76.net/   thats my website, if you can take a look, I need to adjust the footer in order to match  the header size too, and i need to know how it can be done in order to put content in between the header and footer with fixed positions too!! Thank you for your help

Comment: @user3676224 you are missing "left: 0" in the declaration for .footer. Also apply the background color (#000) to your .content element and not to the footer to make it look like the header.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick!!! I have one other question i would like to ask, if you don't mind. the top "navbar" has white-space: nowrap; which causes it to over flow the content on window resize. I have tried to apply the same trick, and even removed white-space: nowrap; however, it doesn't shrink the nav bar to fit that the space. Do you know of a trick that could solve this issue? or any suggestions? THank you so much!

Comment: I think you're better offing using a framework like Bootstrap. Otherwise try playing around with float:left on your links. @user3676224

Comment: I will, for other websites, but this one I would like to build computely from scratch

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because containers with `position:fixed` are removed from the normal flow of the document. You should add margins to your `fixed` element instead.